# Is a Mac Pro sufficient for a webserver

Tags: webserver

We're currently using a Mac Mini 2012 edition to test run our upcoming website. However we're going to be expecting around 30,000-50,000 users per day later on after we launch.

My question is, will a maxed out Mac Pro with these specs be enough to handle this volume of users

- Two 3.06GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon (12 cores)
- 64GB (8x8GB)
- 4x 512GB solid-state drive
- ATI Radeon HD 5770 1GB
- One 18x SuperDrive
- Quad-channel 4Gb Fibre Channel PCI Express card

Any other suggestions are welcome as well. We tried hosted service before but it was just too limited for our needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on your website design - for static content this machine is overpowered, for dynamic content it depends on programming and query structure.

Have you considered using Amazons EC2? You'll reach more fault tolerance and scalability than you do with a single Mac Pro.

Comment: We're using wordpress as our CMS, so that would be php along with MySQL. The thing is, we've just relocated to China and the firewall issue means that a lot of things get patchy when we outsource our servers externally. 

Would you say the Mac pro is enough for our situation?

Comment: Additionally the site will be running large numbers of php curl requests for external content and serving flash ads at the same time, for a single test user the mac mini is fine but for larger number of users it really hangs.

Comment: From my experience php-curl is really memory exhausting - anyway, the question is this box is suiting your needs is still depending on the actual programming and db usage - the SSD setup will significantly increase you db performance in comparison to hdd but I would still suggest you to work out a concept for an eventual loadbalancing, before deploying the website.

Comment: Do you have any alternatives to php curl? I tried file_get_contents but apparently other users are saying it's slower than curl. 

In terms of load balancing would you recommend local hardware load balancers i.e several macs or using a service like cloudflare for "cloud" load balancing?

Comment: And do you think 10Mbps upload speed is enough for a site like this. We're evaluating different ISP providers but for some reason each one seems to love lying out of their teeth i.e saying they sell us 50Mbps speed when in fact we only get 5Mbps.

Comment: Curl alternatives are use case depending - do you need the foreign content on every hit on you page or could it maybe fetched just on regular basis? - This could be also done with cron... Load balancing is a complex area, where you also cannot make a single recommendation - For the beginning I would suggets you to have a look into DNS based loadbalancing and mod_proxy_(balancer). 10Mbps would be a little tight IMHO.

Comment: Yea the external content will need to be loaded each time a post is loaded. Basically I'm using curl to replace iframed contente from before. By cronjob do you mean saving the content in a file, like Caching and then serve it to the user? Would that reduce server processing by much.

Comment: Some sort of caching is what I was heading for - If you do this by cron or whatever, this is up to you - It will definitely decrase load.